# Conways game of Life with 1D array

Tags: arrays, rust, conways-game-of-life, rust-wasm

Right now I'm doing this [tutorial](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/implementing.html) for WebAssembly with Rust. The task is to implement [Conways Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) in Rust. Writing a low-level language like Rust is new for me, but with my prior experience in coding I understand most of the syntax.

The problem I'm having is about the logic of this function:

```
    fn live_neighbor_count(&self, row: u32, column: u32) -> u8 {
        let mut count = 0;
        for delta_row in [self.height - 1, 0, 1].iter().cloned() {
            for delta_col in [self.width - 1, 0, 1].iter().cloned() {
                if delta_row == 0 && delta_col == 0 {
                    continue;
                }

                let neighbor_row = (row + delta_row) % self.height;
                let neighbor_col = (column + delta_col) % self.width;
                let idx = self.get_index(neighbor_row, neighbor_col);
                count += self.cells[idx] as u8;
            }
        }
        count
    }
```

In this implementation of [Conways Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) the grid of cells is represented as an one-dimensional array. The task of this function is now to take coordinates (`row` and `column`) and iterate around the neighbours of this coordinates. Because the array is only one-dimensional, the tasks requires `delta_row` and `delta_col` which iterate over a array to calculate the neighbors.

My problem is now to understand why these arrays `[self.height - 1, 0, 1]` and `[self.height - 1, 0, 1]` are choosen to be iterated over.

I already tried to print out the iterated values and draw the grid on a pieces of paper to visualize the process. Right now I also try to implement a self-written function to understand the choices of the above function better.

Maybe you have already solved this or a similar problem and can give me a hints what's going on.

Thank you for reading and have a nice weekend!

Comment: It's a modulo hack. The trick is in the line `(row + delta_row) % self.height`, the three values you get after the modulo operand are `row-1`, `row` and `row+1`.

Comment: Maybe a better way to write this would be `for neighbor_row in (row-1..=row+1) {...}`. No need for modulo then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends up looking a bit odd because of the constraint of unsigned integers (`u32`). What we want to write is

```rust
for delta_row in [-1, 0, 1]
```

which gives every row within 1 of our original, but we can't use `-1` because it has a sign. Notice later that we

```
let neighbor_row = (row + delta_row) % self.height;
```

so really we're effectively working in the integers modulo `self.height`. In this case, `-1 = self.height - 1`, so we are free to substitute the latter (which is legal for a `u32`).

An easy way to see this is to substitute it in later. On the iteration when `delta_row = self.height - 1`, we are doing

```
let neighbor_row = (row + self.height - 1) % self.height;
                 = (row - 1) % self.height - self.height % self.height;
                 = (row - 1) % self.height;
```

which is the row before `row` (with wrapping at the edge).

Answer (score 0):

Inputs:

| self.height | self.width | row | column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 64 | 4 | 6 |

Initially delta_row in creates an array which will have [64-1=63,0,1] and it will replace delta_row as a value with each iteration, so the iteration will look like this:

| delta_row | delta_col | neighbor_row | neigbor_col | idx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | 63 | 4+63 % 64 = 3 | 6+63 % 64 = 5 | get_index(3,5) |
| 63 | 0 | 3 | 6 | get_index(3,6) |
| 63 | 1 | 3 | 7 | get_index(3,7) |
| 0 | 63 | 4 | 5 | get_index(4,5) |
| 0 | 0 | CONTINUED | CONTINUED | CONTINUED |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 7 | get_index(4,7) |
| 1 | 63 | 5 | 5 | get_index(5,5) |
| 1 | 0 | 5 | 6 | get_index(5,6) |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 7 | get_index(5,7) |

See how it sort of does a hollow square around your row and column.
Count is increased by self.cells[idx] which will always be either 0 or 1 as defined by the enum. So the ones that are alive will increase the count.